# XML Prefix soap:Body to soapenv:Body

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, asmx

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetMessageResponse>
         <GetMessageResult>
            <head xmlns="">
               <body>
                  <Inner>welcome</Inner>
                  <Outer>Bye</Outer>
               </body>
            </head>
         </GetMessageResult>
      </GetMessageResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is generated by WCF. the response XML as above.
I would like to change the XML prefix from <**soap:Body**> to <**soapenv:Body**>

 Anyone has this solution?

Comment: When I use soapUI to test my wcf service, my request is a message starting with soapenv.

Comment: Is there a requirement that the prefix should be soapenv instead of soap? Because the xml tooling does not care how the prefix looks like as long as it is defined and points to the correct url. The prefix is nothing more than a placeholder for the actual url that helps users when reading the message.

Comment: @TheobaldDu, by default, the request is soapenv. The soap response always in soap instead of soapenv.

Comment: @martijn, the project's requirement is during the response, the soap prefix must <soapenv:body>, otherwise the legacy system cannot support it. Do you have any advice so far? thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never done it myself but a quick round of googling got me here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230835/wcf-client-forcing-global-namespaces/36368162#36368162 I think this is what you need.