# Adding xml prefix to default serializer in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, rest, wcf

I have a REST service written in vb.net that returns data using the built in serializer, so if I return my data from a Class defined like this:

```
Public Class Minion
    Public Property Name As String = ""
    Public Property ID As String = ""
End Class
```

my xml will return like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Minion xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Testv3">
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Name>Kevin</Name>
</Minion>
```

But how can I add a prefix to my xml elements so I could see something like:

```
<myLevel1:Minion>
   <mylevel2:ID>
```

Would I need to serialize the data myself to do this?

Comment: You can define the namespace generated adding something like this to Minion class: `<DataContract(Name := "Minion", [Namespace] := "your namespace")>`. To control the prefix, you need to implement a serializer, this link can help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17798306/4730201

Comment: thanks for the answer, I think it is as I first thought that I will need to serialize the data myself.  It's annoying as you can set things like ElementName & NameSpace, but not the prefix. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Add the Namespace your Minion Class

```
<XmlRoot([Namespace]:="myLevel1")>
Public Class Minion

    <XmlElement([Namespace]:="myLevel2")>
    Public Property Name As String = ""

    Public Property ID As String = ""

End Class
```

And add the Namespaces to the Serializer:

```
        Dim _xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Minion))

        Dim xn As New XmlSerializerNamespaces
        xn.Add("myLevel1", "myLevel1")
        xn.Add("myLevel2", "myLevel2")

        Using _fs As New FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create)
            _xs.Serialize(_fs, New Minion With {.ID = 1, .Name = "minion1"}, xn)    
        End Using
```

Will give you this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myLevel1:Minion xmlns:myLevel2="myLevel2" xmlns:myLevel1="myLevel1">
  <myLevel2:Name>minion1</myLevel2:Name>
  <myLevel1:ID>1</myLevel1:ID>
</myLevel1:Minion>
```